# how to use nest() in tidyr to collapse several rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame like this

```
df=data.frame(a=rep(c("x","y"),2),b=c("Rome", "Venice", "Barcelona", "Paris"))
```

and i want to nest b by column a such that it shows

```
x  Rome, Barcelona
y  Venice, Paris
```

however this doesn't seem to do the trick. any advice?

As suggested

```
df$b=as.character(df$b)
df=as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(a) %>% nest(b))
```

however the new data column of df seem to be in tbl_df format and result is like this

```
a  data
x  list(b = c("Rome", "Barcelona")
```

is there a way to make the new nested column just normal string combinations?

Comment: What about this `aggregate(data=df,b~a,toString)`?

Comment: as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(a) %>% nest(b))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are not wedded to a `tidyr` / `nest` solution, you can do this with just `dplyr` using:

```
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(b = paste(b, collapse = ", "))
```

which returns:

```
       a               b
  <fctr>           <chr>
1      x Rome, Barcelona
2      y   Venice, Paris
```

If you want to use `nest`, you can use `map_chr` from `purrr` to do what you want as well:

```
df %>%
  mutate(b = as.character(b)) %>%
  nest(b) %>%
  mutate(cityList = map_chr(data, ~paste(.$b, collapse = ", "))) %>%
  select(-data)
```

Note that, as @joel.wilson pointed out, for this, you will likely need to explicitly convert the city names to a character if they are a factor. It returns this:

```
       a        cityList
  <fctr>           <chr>
1      x Rome, Barcelona
2      y   Venice, Paris
```

Answer (score 3):

ensure that `column b` is a character : then do the following,

```
as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(a) %>% nest(b))
#  a            data
#1 x Rome, Barcelona
#2 y   Venice, Paris
```

If `column b` is a factor :then the levels will be outputted

```
> class(df$b)
[1] "factor"
> df$b
[1] Rome      Venice    Barcelona Paris    
Levels: Barcelona Paris Rome Venice

> as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(a) %>% nest(b))
#  a data
#1 x 3, 1
#2 y 4, 2
```

with the changes you have asked : try the following code :df1 is o/p from as.data.frame()

```
df1 = df %>% group_by(a) %>% nest(b)    
df1$newcol = sapply(df1$data, function(x) paste(x$b, collapse = ","))
df1

       a           data         newcol
#  (fctr)          (chr)          (chr)
#1      x <tbl_df [2,1]> Rome,Barcelona
#2      y <tbl_df [2,1]>   Venice,Paris
```

Comment: and sometimes after the nested column become: list(b = c("Rome", "Barcelona")). why would that happen?

Comment: I didn't get you.. could you share a reproducible example? re-edit the question itself

Comment: thanks for ur reply. have edit the question. 
so if run 
df=as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(a) %>% nest(b)) 
then 
str(df) it shows data column as tbl_df class like this:
data
1
x
list(b = c("Rome", "Barcelona"))
2
y
list(b = c("Venice", "Paris"))